# C# QuickGraph - Planar Graph Traversal - Faces

Tags: c#, graph, graph-theory, quickgraph, planar-graph

Is there a way to find faces of a graph using QuickGraph for C#, similar to the Planar Face Traversal function in the Boost C++ Graph Library?

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/doc/planar_face_traversal.html

Comment: It doesn't seem so, I couldn't find such algorithm in the original library or any of more up-to-date forks at github